# Does uniform conditional distribution imply independence?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, independence, uniform-distribution

Take two random variable $X,Y$ and suppose $X$ is distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$ conditional on $Y$. Does this imply that $X$ is independent of $Y$? Could you make an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) would mean that knowing the value of $Y$ gives no information on the value of $X$.

So here $X$ will be independent of $Y$ only if $X$ has a uniform [marginal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) on $[0,1]$, and the conditional distribution $X|Y$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ *independent* of the value of $Y$.

An example be a uniform [(joint) distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_distribution) over the unit square.

---

Here are some examples using [Tetris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris) blocks:

For the "S" block

[image: Tetris "S" block (rotated)]

we have $p[X|Y=\text{middle}]=p[X]=\text{uniform}$, but $X$ is certainly **not** independent of $Y$.

While for the "O" block

[image: Tetris "O" block]

we have $p[X|Y]=p[X]=\text{uniform}$, so $X$ **is** independent of $Y$.

Comment: Thanks. However is it true that if $X$ conditional on $Y$ is distributed as a standard Normal then $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: So can I say that "the standard normal exception does not apply to the uniform"?

Comment: I might have misunderstood. If $X|Y$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ for all $Y$ values, then yes it is independent: The value of $Y$ does not enter into the formula for $p[X|Y]$. I thought you meant just you had one particular $Y$ value.

Comment: So the point is that it is not the particular form of $p[X|Y]$ that matters, but the fact that it does not depend on the value of $Y$.

Comment: I added an example of $X$ uniform for only *some* $Y$, where the marginal is uniform but $X$ **does** depend on $Y$.

Comment: @user3285148: There's no such thing as "the standard normal exception". (Source: A Google search for this exact phrase gives only this question, and some unrelated Linkedin profiles). As GeoMatt22 explains, it's not the particular form of the conditional distribution that matters (be it Uniform, Normal, Gamma or whatever), only that it is the same distribution for every possible value of Y.

Answer (score 1):

If the conditional pdf of $X$ given $Y$ is the *same* density function for all values of $Y$ (in the support of $f_Y(y)$), that is, $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)$ equals $g(x)$ where the value of $g$ does not depend on $y$ at all, then
$$f_X(x) = \int f_{X,Y}(x,y) \mathrm dy  = \int f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\cdot f_Y(y)\mathrm dy = g(x)\int f_Y(y)\mathrm dy = g(x),$$ that is, the unconditional pdf of $X$ is the same as the common conditional pdf
of $X$ given $Y$. *In particular,*
uniformity does not have anything to do with it at all: what we need is that it is always the same density function regardless of the value of $y$.

Suppose that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ has value $1$ on (the interior of) the unit square. Then $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) \sim U(0,1)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are both
independent  $U(0,1)$ random variables.

Suppose that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ has value $2y$ on (the interior of) the unit square. Then $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) \sim U(0,1)$, and $X \sim U(0,1)$ also. Note that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables but $Y$ is *not* a $U(0,1)$ random variable.

Suppose that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ has value $2x$ on (the interior of) the unit square. Then $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = 2x\mathbf 1_{\{x\colon x \in (0,1)\}}$ and the unconditional density of $X$ is the same density.  $X$ and $Y$  are independent random variables but $X$ is *not* a $U(0,1)$ random variable. Uniform distribution of $X$ is *not* needed: what is needed is that $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)$ is the same for all choices of
$y$.